# Pass Web page into php object using Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework2

How to pass HTML script from a link "example.com" to variable $html? So later would be possible to manipulate with $html variable:

```
use Zend\Dom\Query;

$dom = new Query($html);
$results = $dom->execute('.foo .bar a'); 

$count = count($results); // get number of matches: 4
foreach ($results as $result) {
    // $result is a DOMElement
}
```

Where variable $html represents web page HTML script.

Comment: what is your question again?

Comment: How can i pass HTML script from a link "http://example.com" to variable $html?

Comment: like ``$html = file_get_contents('http://example.com');`` ?

Comment: Just using Zend Framework components.

Comment: Tried just now, works fine with get_contents. Appreciate for not letting me search through Zend Framework Manual for hours. But if you know a way to do similar in Zend Framework please show here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Answer:

```
    $html = file_get_contents('http://example.com');
```

Complex ZF2 Answer:

```
    $client = new \Zend\Http\Client();
    $client->setUri('http://example.com');
    $client->send();
    $response = $client->getResponse();

    if( $response->getStatusCode() == 200 )
    {
        $html = $response->getBody();
        // do more stuff dom etc...
    }
```